# joining two sql statements vertically

Tags: php, mysql

I want to join the following two sql statements into one so that I have total 23 rows( First sql has 23 rows and second has 20 rows out of this 20 rows are common with unique field location in each sql)  with h3dac values in first sql and 2nd sql appear in columns.

Any work around please ?

```
$sql_u1="select * from (select location1.location as locs, location1.elevation as elvn,location1.group as groups, shiftdata.location as loc1,  shiftdata.date,  shiftdata.shift,  shiftdata.h3dac as h3dac1 from location1 inner join shiftdata on location1.location=shiftdata.location where shiftdata.unit= 1 ORDER BY shiftdata.date desc, shiftdata.shift desc, location1.loc_id limit 23) as a left JOIN  (select location as loc1, date as date2, shift as shift2, h3dac as h3dac2  from shiftdata where unit= 1 ORDER BY date desc, shift desc limit 23 offset 23) as b on a.locs=b.loc1 left join (select location as loc3, date as date3, shift as shift3, h3dac as h3dac3 from shiftdata where unit= 1 ORDER BY date desc, shift desc limit 23 offset 46) as c on a.locs=c.loc3";

$sql_u2="select * from (select location2.location as locs,location2.elevation as elvn, location2.group as groups, shiftdata.location as loc1,  shiftdata.date,  shiftdata.shift,  shiftdata.h3dac as h3dac1 from location2 inner join shiftdata on location2.location=shiftdata.location where shiftdata.unit= 2 ORDER BY shiftdata.date desc, shiftdata.shift desc, location2.loc_id limit 20) as a left JOIN  (select location as loc1, date as date2, shift as shift2, h3dac as h3dac2 from shiftdata where unit= 2 ORDER BY date desc, shift desc limit 20 offset 20) as b on a.locs=b.loc1 left join (select location as loc3, date as date3, shift as shift3, h3dac as h3dac3 from shiftdata where unit= 2 ORDER BY date desc, shift desc limit 20 offset 40) as c on a.locs=c.loc3";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql ="select * from (sel....
    union  
    select * from (sel....
```

You can use union operation, it will return you the result without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If your two sql statements return same data types columns and same number of columns you can use union.

$sql = $sql_u1. " UNION " . $sql_u2

Comment: would give syntax error.. it needs to be " UNION " as there are no spaces at the end of $sql_u1

Comment: Fixed that. Thanks.